# Варианты эффекта наведение на продукт каталога

Tags: html, css

К примеру есть такой список продуктов каталога:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px .5% 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.item:hover {
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #ccc;
}

.s-box {
  width: 100%;
  background: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  
  display: none;
}

.item:hover .s-box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Задача в том, что оранжевый блок `.s-box` может иметь разный контент (высота не фиксирована). Изначально этот блок скрыт, но при наведении на продукт `.item` этот блок должен появляться. Но при этом структура сетки не должна нарушаться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если бы была фиксированная высота скрываемого блока, то обычно пробую отрицательным margin варьировать:

```
.item:hover {
  margin-bottom: -38px;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #ccc;
}

.item:hover .s-box {
  display: block;
}
```

но с нижними пунктами происходит беда, особенно если внизу должен быть отступ тоже в 10 пикселей всего и следом идет уже другой блок страницы.

**Вопрос:** какие есть варианты решения наведения в таком списке?

**P.S:** Пункты (продукты) идут списком, т.е. по 4 в отдельный `.row` помещать нельзя.

Comment: Ну а почему не position: absolute с частичным перекрытием нижнего блока, как показано на картинке? Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: А если надо динамически раздвинуть ряды, то засунуть ряд в div .row clear: both;, его сделать display: table;, li сделать display: table-cell; float: none; vertical-align: top;.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, видимо чего-то не поняли и нет нельзя row (если вы о том чтобы каждые 4 пункта в row засовывать), и table-cell соответственно нет

Comment: Почему нельзя? В вопросе этого нет. Что, доступа к php нет?

Comment: хотя предложите свой вариант, вопрос ведь в том как кто делает, потому как я обычно "костылями" такое делаю

Comment: Предложу завтра утром. Сегодня уже без компа, иначе уже бы дал ответ.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, теперь условие есть) нет доступа конечно же нет, потому как работа верстальщика html css

Comment: да тут уже сделали два отличных варианта. Так что предлагать свой смысла не вижу.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, ясно понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если кол-во изначально отображаемого контента ограничено, то можно
   карточкам продуктов задать фиксированную высоту:

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background: #ccc;
    }

    .item {
      width: 24%;
      height: 324px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0px .5% 10px;
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .item-inner {
      padding: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .s-box {
      width: 100%;
      background: orangered;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      display: none;
    }

    .item:hover {
      z-index: 1;
      overflow: visible;
    }

    .item:hover .item-inner {
      height: auto;
    }

    .item:hover .s-box {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

2. Поигравшись немного с отступами и позицией, получаем:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px .5% 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.item-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right:-1px;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
}

.s-box {
  background: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item:hover .item-hover {
  display: block;
}

.item:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="item-hover">
      <div class="s-box">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="item-hover">
      <div class="s-box">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="item-hover">
      <div class="s-box">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="item-hover">
      <div class="s-box">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="item-hover">
      <div class="s-box">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="item-hover">
      <div class="s-box">
        Lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

3. С использованием jQuery:

```js
function items() {
      $('.hidden').each(function() {
        $(this).css('padding-top', $(this).closest('.item').find('.visible').outerHeight());
      });
    }
    items();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      items();
    });
```

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .item {
      width: 24%;
      float: left;
      margin: 0px .5% 10px;
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
    }

    .item:hover {
      z-index: 5;
    }

    .img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background: #ccc;
    }

    .text {
      padding: 0 5px;
    }

    .visible {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .hidden {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
      box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #ccc;
      display: none;
    }

    .s-box {
      width: 100%;
      background: orangered;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .item:hover .visible {
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

    .item:hover .hidden {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="visible">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="visible">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="visible">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="visible">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="visible">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="visible">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <div class="s-box">
            Lorem ipsum
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @HamSter ,  какое пустое место?

Comment: @HamSter варианты с использованием js/jquery не рассмытриваются?)

Comment: А как все таки быть с высотой карточек? Они ведь будут "скакать", если  кол-во текста в .text будет разное

Answer (score 1):

Реализовал на столько, на сколько смог понять задачу. Изменения коснулись только .item в css. Также хочу посоветовать не использовать float, сейчас его считают злом. Обязательно почитайте про flexbox и забудьте про float.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0px .5% 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.s-box {
  width: 100%;
  background: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  
  display: none;
}

.item:hover .s-box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, voluptates.
    </div>
    <div class="s-box">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```