# Как вывести при наведении дополнтельную информацию

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, style

Хочу что бы при :hover было так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока что сделал так, а как дальше не пойму
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код прилогается.

```
<div class="col-md-3 mag_posit" style="position: relative;">
            <a href="#" class="mag_posit1" >
            <img class="sales" src="img/sales.png" />
            <div class="sales_txt">-15%</div>
            <img src="img/bike.png" alt="bike">
            <div class="rating">
                <span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span><span>&#9734;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="time_pos">
                <button class="btn time_pos_bt">new</button>
            </div>
            <div class="name_bike">
                <span>Bergamont Vitox 26</span>
            </div>
            <div class="type_bike">
                <span>Велосипед</span>
            </div>
            <div class="started">
                 <span>12096</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span>10519 грн.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="point">
                <span style="font-family:OpenSans-Italic;">+</span>1200 BikeПоинтов
            </div>
            <span class="fa fa-heart" style="margin-left: 10px;" >
            <span class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="margin-left: 5px;">
            </span></span>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn_baces">В КОРЗИНУ</button>
            <div class="vidor_diag" style="display: none;">
            <select class="form-control">
                    <option>16” (160 - 170 см)</option>
                    <option>16” (160 - 170 см)</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Стили

```
.mag_posit1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#333333;
}
.mag_posit1:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#333333;
}
.mag_posit:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#333333;
    border: 4px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}
.see_all{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:18px; 
    font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#333333;
    margin-top:30px; 
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.see_all:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#333333;
}
```

Comment: Варианты реализации подобных карточек можно найти тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691566/209956

Comment: @Cheg Спасибо! Разобрался